# Как плавно отобразить SVG картинку, при скроле или ховере

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, svg, анимация

[image: описание]

Как мне сделать так что бы когда я наводил на какой то блок, к нему рисовалась эта svg картинка, ниже код самой svg а именно вот этой -

[image: description]

Код самой svg:

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                             viewBox="0 0 94.62 135.04">
                                            <g class="this-path">
                                                <path class="cls-1"
                                                      d="M91.88,135.04c-.06,0-.12-.01-.19-.04l-.6-.24c-.26-.1-.38-.39-.28-.65,.1-.26,.39-.38,.65-.28l.6,.24c.26,.1,.38,.39,.28,.65-.08,.2-.27,.31-.46,.31Z"/>
                                                <path class="cls-1"
                                                      d="M89.26,133.61c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.43-.25c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.43,.25c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Z"/>
                                                <path class="cls-1"
                                                      d="M87.08,132.34c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.44-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.44-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68s.44-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68s.44-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.63-1.53c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.88-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.88,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Z"/>
                                                <path class="cls-1"
                                                      d="M26.55,97.16c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.43-.25c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.44-.32,.68-.18l.43,.25c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Z"/>
                                                <path class="cls-1"
                                                      d="M25.04,96.32c-.08,0-.15-.02-.22-.05l-1.2-.6,1.12-.84c.22-.17,.53-.12,.7,.1,.14,.18,.13,.42,0,.6,.11,.15,.13,.35,.05,.52-.09,.18-.26,.28-.45,.28Z"/>
                                                <path class="cls-1"
                                                      d="M27.19,94.53c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.24-.14-.24-.06-.54,.17-.69l.43-.26c.24-.14,.54-.06,.69,.17,.14,.24,.06,.54-.17,.69l-.43,.26c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Z"/>
                                                <path class="cls-1"
                                                      d="M29.35,93.25c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.18-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.69,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.18,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.18-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.69,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.18,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.18-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.69,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.18,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.18-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.55-.06,.69,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.18,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.18-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.69,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.18,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.18-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.55-.06,.69,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.18,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.18-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.69,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.18,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.18-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.55-.06,.69,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.18,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.18-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.69,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.18,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.18-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.69,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.18,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.18-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.55-.06,.69,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.18,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.18-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.69,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.18,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.18-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.69,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.18,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.18-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.69,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.18,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.17-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.68,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.17,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.17-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.68,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.17,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.17-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.68,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.17,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.17-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.68,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.17,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.17-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.68,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.17,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.17-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.68,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.17,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.18-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.68,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.17,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.17-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.69,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.18,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.17-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.68,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.17,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Zm2.6-1.54c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.18-.69l.87-.51c.24-.14,.54-.06,.69,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.18,.69l-.87,.51c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Z"/>
                                                <path class="cls-1"
                                                      d="M91.69,56.3c-.17,0-.34-.09-.43-.25-.14-.24-.06-.54,.17-.69l.43-.25c.24-.14,.54-.06,.68,.18,.14,.24,.06,.54-.17,.69l-.43,.25c-.08,.05-.17,.07-.25,.07Z"/>
                                                <path class="cls-1"
                                                      d="M93.19,55.45c-.18,0-.36-.1-.45-.28-.09-.17-.06-.38,.05-.52-.13-.17-.13-.42,0-.6,.17-.22,.48-.26,.7-.1l1.12,.84-1.2,.6c-.07,.04-.15,.05-.22,.05Z"/>
                                                <path class="cls-1"
                                                      d="M91.05,53.66c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.43-.25c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.43,.25c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Z"/>
                                                <path class="cls-1"
                                                      d="M88.87,52.4c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.44-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68s.44-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.44-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68s.44-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.44-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68s.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.45-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.44-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68s.44-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.44-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.44-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.44-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Zm-2.62-1.52c-.09,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.87-.51c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.44-.32,.68-.18l.87,.51c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Z"/>
                                                <path class="cls-1"
                                                      d="M2.48,2.2c-.08,0-.17-.02-.25-.07l-.43-.25c-.24-.14-.32-.44-.18-.68,.14-.24,.44-.32,.68-.18l.43,.25c.24,.14,.32,.44,.18,.68-.09,.16-.26,.25-.43,.25Z"/>
                                                <path class="cls-1"
                                                      d="M.98,1.36c-.1,0-.21-.03-.3-.1L.2,.9C-.02,.73-.07,.42,.1,.2,.27-.02,.58-.06,.8,.1l.48,.36c.22,.17,.27,.48,.1,.7-.1,.13-.25,.2-.4,.2Z"/>
                                            </g>
                                        </svg>
```

Отдельно все же выделю вопрос спасибо.

- **Как мне сделать анимацию появления SVG при ховере или по моменту скрола?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это нерационально: использовать отдельные `path` для каждого штриха линии.
Есть более простой способ сделать пунктирную линию с закругленными концами каждого сегмента линии.
Для этого используйте `stroke-dasharray` и `lineCap="round"`

```html
<svg id="svg4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  viewBox="0 0 615 445">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH9bB.png" id="image2" height="100%" width="100%"/>
   <rect id="rect" x="250" y="0" width="100" height="150" fill="transparent" stroke="#DEDEDE"/>
  <path d="m315.8 151.3 76.9 44.3-57 33 56.5 34.4" id="path4520" fill="none" stroke="#3B3B3B" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"  stroke-dasharray="4 5">
</path>
</svg>
```

Для анимации при наведении на блок, используем команду:

```
<animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="rect.mouseover"
  end="rect.mouseleave" dur="2s" values="200;0" />
```

```html
<svg id="svg4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"   viewBox="0 0 615 445">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH9bB.png" id="image2" height="100%" width="100%"/>
   <rect id="rect" x="250" y="0" width="100" height="150" fill="transparent" stroke="#DEDEDE"/>
  <path d="m315.8 151.3 76.9 44.3-57 33 56.5 34.4" id="path4520" fill="none" stroke="#3B3B3B" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"  stroke-dasharray="4 5">
   <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="rect.mouseover" end="rect.mouseleave" dur="2s" values="200;0" /> 
   </path>
 </svg>
```

### Вариант CSS

```css
#rect {
fill:transparent;
stroke:#DEDEDE;
}
#rect:hover ~ #path4520 {
animation: stroke 4s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
0%{stroke-dashoffset:221px;}
 100%{stroke-dashoffset:0px;}
}
#path4520  {
fill:none;
stroke:#3B3B3B;
stroke-width:2;
stroke-linecap:round;
stroke-dasharray:4, 5;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"   viewBox="0 0 615 445">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH9bB.png" id="image2" height="100%" width="100%"/>
   <rect id="rect" x="250" y="0" width="100" height="150" />
  <path d="m315.8 151.3 76.9 44.3-57 33 56.5 34.4" id="path4520" >
  
   </path>
 </svg>
```